# setText doesn't set text to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I'm having a problem that I've never had before in almost three years of developing with Android...

I want to take a picture and after the picture is taked, the `EditText`s of the activity become clear. What I'm doing is set the values of the `EditText` to `Strings` using `getText().toString()` to restore them after taking the picture.

The strings are stored perfectly with the data, but when I use `setText`, it doesn't work... The strange thing is that `setHint` works!

How can it be?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent

                grabImage(imgView);

                for (int u = 0; u <= 2; u++)
                {
                    if (savedImgs[u].equals(""))
                    {
                        imgs = u + 1;
                        savedImgs[u] = photo.toString();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                /*Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); ---> It is a small bitmap, for icons...
                imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image couldn't be taken. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        if (!tempSpotName.equals("") || !tempSpotDesc.equals("")) {

            name.setText(tempSpotName);
            description.setText(tempSpotDesc);
        }
    }
```

`name` and `description` are global `EditTexts` and `tempSpotName` and `tempSpotDesc` are global `Strings`.

How can I set the text?

Comment: may we see your layout xml code? Do you even reach             name.setText(tempSpotName); ? Did you debug this?

Comment: Just checking, but setText is getting called but not displaying correct? The the if statement isnt preventing it from being called? (just double checking since setText should work)

Comment: Are you calling `setText()` anywhere else? Possibly in `onResume()`?

Comment: @Goot and @AJak Yes, I rech the if statement and it is being called. Otherwise `setHint` won't work...
@Sam I think I call it in the onCreate()... I'm gonna check it...

Comment: @Sam okey... I didn't realize I was calling setText in the onCreate()... I'm genius lol Thank you very much! If you answer I'll check it as the accepted answert!

Comment: how come the text will stay empty when you call setText(value) AFTER the view was created?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` is not the last method called when returning to an Activity. You can refresh your memory of [the Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) in the docs. :)

As we discussed in the comments, if you call `setText()` again in methods like `onResume()` this will override any text set in `onActivityResult()`.

The same goes for Fragments, you need to make updates in onViewStateRestored() method (which was added in API 17).

Comment: Any changes in onResume() also overrides changes in onNewIntent().

Comment: The same goes for Fragments, you need to make updates in onViewStateRestored() method (which was added in API 17).

Answer (score 10):

Some times changing `edittext` in `onactivity` result is not working. I too faced the same problem

instead of setting

```
edittext.settext("yourtext");
```

change to following in `onactivityresult`

```
edittext.post(new Runnable(){
edittext.settext("yourtext");
});
```

It worked for me.

Comment: probably     edittext.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                edittext.setText("yourtext");  /*and note setText is caMel */
            }
        });

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to debug this.

There is a class called TextWatcher. This will be called every time your Textbox.Text will change. So this is easier to debug and handle the problem. Url: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Example for implementation:

```
name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        doSomething();



    } 

});
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can force a EditText.SetText("blablabla..."); inside your OnActivity Result 
in 3 EASY steps:

1. Reload your layout into your Activity
2. Rebind your EditText
3. use SetText as usual.

In this sample code, I pass a URL string with and intent and write it into a TextView:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{       
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        QRdata= data.getStringExtra("QRURL");

        if (QRdata.length()>0)
        {
                            //Step1
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmpackage); 
                            //Step2
            TextView qrtxt=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.qrurl); 
                            //Setp 3,Voilà!
            qrtxt.setText(QRdata.toString()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this solve works for me (kotlin)

```
val editText= EditText(context)
editText.apply {
   layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTEXT
        )}
editText.doOnPreDraw {
    editText.setText("your text")
}
```