# Onactivityresult is not working fine in nested fragment class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have `mainfragment.java` and am added the `viewpager` in `mainfragment.java`. In that viewpager have `mobile_fragment.java`.When i click the edit-text in `mobile_fragment.java` using **Intent** to open the phone contacts after user click the contacts, get the result using **Onactivityresult**, but the result was not coming in `mobile_fragment.java`. The **Onactivityresult** comes till `mainfragment.java`, not comes for `mobile_fragment.java` in viewpager. I think the problem comes for nested fragment.I done some thing in both class but i got `NullpointerException` error.I don't know how to solve this issue.Please help me out to solve this issue.

**mainfragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (other_fragments != null){

            String phoneNo = null ;
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);

            Intent output = new Intent();
            output.putExtra("number", ""+phoneNo);

            other_fragments.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, output);

        }
    }
```

**mobile_fragment.java**

```
//This fragment i have edit-text.
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {

            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {


                String te=data.getStringExtra("number");
                Log.v("TAG_TA",""+te);
               // It prints the log values correctly.
                prepaid_mobilenum_edt.setText(""+data.getStringExtra("number"));//NullPointerException comes here.
            }
  }
```

**Error log**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/80704 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.reloadapp.reload/com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2997)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3040)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1191)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Mobile_Fragment.onActivityResult(Mobile_Fragment.java:1236)
            at com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Main_frag_one.onActivityResult(Main_frag_one.java:97)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:163)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2993)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3040)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1191)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Also, where are you assigning a value to `prepaid_mobilenum_edt`?

Comment: Solution for your problem is same like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387318/settext-doesnt-set-text-to-edittext

Comment: that´s not the complete stacktrace....please post the complete one

Comment: Make sure that `prepaid_mobilenum_edt` isn't null. Where you assign his value?

Comment: @Rami...this is nested fragment concept. In this i wrote onActivtiyresult. In onActivityresult i want to the data to edit text. I intialized the edit text too

Comment: please any one help me

Comment: any one help me,,,,please